# How do you display hyperlinks without an underline?

Tags: html, css

How do you display hyperlinks without an underline ?

Comment: IIRC some browsers have an "always underline links" option which you won't be able to override.  if that option isn't set however, the answers you've already gotten should do the trick.

Comment: Read the [CSS3 Text Specs](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-text/#decoration).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0000CC;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0000CC;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

(Or at least that's how [we](http://www.ccrfcd.org) do it.)

Oh, and the *order* above matters, by the way.

Comment: +1 for making me learn something new ("Oh, and the order above matters, by the way.") and another +1 (if possible :P) for excellent reply.

Answer (score 4):

```
a:link, a:visited {
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Apply this style:

```
text-decoration: none;
```