# Creating HyperLinks without being underlined

Tags: html, css

I have a simple question about creating hyperlinks..
   
   
   clickme
   
   
 creates a hyperlink but click me would be underlined...
How do I create a hyperlink where links would not be underlined..Should I be using css??

Thanks

Comment: What @eckes means is that you should check the tick on the best answer that worked for you, so other people get a benefit from your question, too. In case there will be a better answer, yet, you still can switch.

Comment: This might be a duplicate question. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267820/how-do-you-display-hyperlinks-without-an-underline/9106888#9106888).

Answer (score 9):

use css. something like this:

```
a
{
text-decoration: none;
}
```

to restore underline on hover:

```
a:hover
{
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

you may replace a with a class selector or an Id.

EDIT: typos;

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use css.

`<a href="link" style="text-decoration: none;">asdf</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Use css for hiding underline from anchor tag:

'a:link { text-decoration: none}'

http://jsfiddle.net/sushant_ceb/L9KNT/

Answer (score 0):

To disable underline for all hyperlinks in the document, use

```
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
<!-- 
  A:link {text-decoration: none}
-->
</STYLE>
```

in the head of your HTML-File.

To only disable underlining for certain hyperlinks, use

```
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
<!-- 
  A:link.nounderline {text-decoration: none}
-->
</STYLE>
```

and define hyperlinks not to be underlined as usual (`<a href="://www.google.com">Google</a>`), but use your `nounderline` class for those that shall not be underlined:

```
<a class="nounderline" href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
```

Comment: Do not include the `<!-- ... -->`, as they are semantically wrong. Instead use `/*<![CDATA[*/ ... /*]]>*/` (both for CSS and JS).

Answer (score 0):

To read more about what you can do with text decoration (besides merely underlining or not), read the [CSS3 Text Specs](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-text/#decoration).